# how to stop interruption for all tests on first failure in cypress

Tags: javascript, cucumber, cypress, lighthouse, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I have a task to go to multiple pages and generate a lighthouse report for each and every page. so I implemented generating the lighthouse report part and also I created an excel file and add all the web page's URLs. It means now I implemented reading the excel file and getting URLs one by one and going to that page and doing the lighthouse test.

```
    //calculationStoryService
    export function getLighthouseAuditForCalculationStory() {
        getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel().then(stories => {
            stories.forEach(story => {
                cy.visit(story.url);
                cy.wait(Cypress.env("storyTableViewResultColumnCheckLoadingTimeout"));
                lighthouseAudit(story.name); // generating lighthouse report
            });
        });
}
```

I am generating lighthouse reports by using a package called "**cypress-audit**" to generate the lighthouse report we need to give base value of single page

```
function lighthouseAudit(name) {
    let baseValueData = getBaseValueData();
    let desktopConfig= getDesktopConfig();

    const lighthouseMetrics = {
            performance: baseValueData.performance,
            accessibility: baseValueData.accessibility,
            seo: baseValueData.seo,
            pwa: baseValueData.pwa
     };


     cy.lighthouse(lighthouseMetrics, desktopConfig);
}
```

when I am calling "**lighthouseAudit**" method I am passing "**story.name**" as a parameter.
it's a unique id for each and every page. so "**lighthouseAudit**" method knows how to get
"**baseValueData**" using that unique id.

when the "**lighthouseAudit**" method running, it doing a lighthouse test and compares the values with base values if some value is less than the base value it will fail the test
that is how it's working and it's working fine.

[image]

this is my test file and where I called the "**getLighthouseAuditForCalculationStory**" method

```
import { Given, Then } from "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/steps";
import { signIn } from "../../../support/services/commonServices";
import { getLighthouseAuditForCalculationStory } from "../../../support/services/calculationStoryService";

Given('Logged in', () => {
    signIn (Cypress.env('username'), Cypress.env('password'));
});

Then('navigate to page and generate lighthouse audit', () => {
    getLighthouseAuditForCalculationStory();
});
```

as I explained "**getLighthouseAuditForCalculationStory**" gets all web page URLs iterating through the list and visiting the page. after it runs the lighthouse test. let's say as an example if the first-page lighthouse test failed, then the loop stopped from there. i want to continue the loop and visit all the pages and do the lighthouse test even though one failed. it interrupts to entire loop if one test fails.

how to continue the loop even though the lighthouse test fails for one web page

packages list

```
 "@cypress-audit/lighthouse": "^1.3.1",
 "cypress": "^10.9.0",
 "cypress-audit": "^1.1.0",
 "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1"
```

Answer (score 4):

A couple of things to try:

Suppress the fail with an event handler.

```js
export function getLighthouseAuditForCalculationStory() {
  Cypress.on('fail', (error, runnable) => {
    if (error.message.includes('A threshold has been crossed') {
      return false
    }
  })
  getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel().then(stories => {
    ...
```

This may not behave as you want, an alternative is to try to create one test per story.

**Spec**

```js
Cypress.env('stories').forEach(story => {

  it(`Testing story: "${story.url}"`, () => {
    cy.visit(story.url);
    cy.wait(Cypress.env("storyTableViewResultColumnCheckLoadingTimeout"));
    lighthouseAudit(story.name); // generating lighthouse report
  })

})
```

The `stories` environment variable would have to be created in `cypress.config.js` using [Before Spec API](https://docs.cypress.io/api/plugins/before-spec-api)

```js
const { defineConfig } = require('cypress')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      on('before:spec', (spec) => {
        getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel().then(stories => {
          config.env['stories'] = stories
        })
      })
    }
  }
})
```

The exact details depend on `getAllCalculationStoriesFromExcel()`, I expect that code already runs in `cypress.config.js` but in a task.

Comment: the first solution is not working. the second one I can't use, because I use cypress cucumber. in that, there are no "**it**" commands